# How to pitch TV show with a 'hook' when have a complete bible and treatments?

Tags: screenwriting, agent

So, I have a TV show I have been writing and will finish soon enough. I have been working on this for a long time, and have written 9 seasons.

The type of show is a sitcom. It is based on my lifestory. The 'hook' I refer to is being transgender, which is a focus for entertainment in many ways at the moment. While that is the hook, the story is a lot more than that.

The premise will be doing a quirky job in a famous coastal city that had a short lifespan, was well known and residents hated. The story of the people doing the job is already interesting. The show focuses on the protagonist and threw flashback covers growing up in a foreign country, leaving home at a young age, traveling around the world before settling in nyc....there is a big arc on personald evelopment and overcoming childhood drama, which turns into a transgender coming out story.

For a sitcom I think I have created something really original, different from anything else that has come before (and I've done a lot of research!).

I have a lot of confidence in the story and episodes, and have complete character sheets, treatments for show and season, and have almost finished writing every script for the 22 episode first season. I will file everything with the WGA. This show has a number of amazing characters and amazing character development for each character, including people of color, women and LGBT people. While it was not written that way deliberately, I do feel it is a selling point.

I am writing it in such a way to try and get a 5 year order, but writing 9 seasons in total, where the story can end after 5, 7 or 9 seasons. I also wrote the first six episodes of the first season to be somewhat self contained. I am confident in my ability to pitch and have different types of presentations prepared.

So, how could I pitch this? I have no background in film or tv, I don't know anyone in the industry, and I am unsure how to send meetings. How would I find an agent to start representing me or the material?

Comment: Has *any* series ever gotten a 5-year order? Is this common in your country? It's extremely *uncommon* in mine (US). I don't think you should target a 5-year order.

Comment: It's not common in the US, but it did happen with the show Supernatural. It's partly uncommon because few people present bibles like Kripke did.

Answer (score 3):

I know we don't like link-only answers, but pitching and finding agents in the film industry is far more than can be told in an answer on this forum.

I highly recommend you look into the courses offered by [Stephanie Palmer](https://goodinaroom.com/write/); author of the book Good in A Room, a veteran of the movie and TV industry. She has detailed courses available on all of this. I do not know her personally and have zero stake in any of her enterprises; but I have tried her instructions and like them. Everything from what the producers WANT in a script, specifically your goals in a pitch, what NOT to say, etc. Unfortunately (for me at least) this typically takes a great deal of social interaction, and if you find an agent they can't do it all alone.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just by coincidence I starting reading a book this morning that could be of interest to you: *The Tipping Point*, by Malcolm Gladwell. I'm only on the first chapter, but it seems to speak to your situation.

From what I have read so far: ideas are like viruses - they need a certain set of circumstances for them to spread. One key part of this is 'connectors' - people who have the ability to connect with other people quickly and easily. Ideas (and TV Programmes) are shared and spread very rapidly when they get into the hands (and heads) of people like this.

You need to find the connectors in your life. You need to communicate your idea to people who know people in the TV and Film industry. You need to start making inroads into a community of people who have the ability to take your idea and make it into a reality for you.

I know that what I've just said seems like a restatement of your problem, and that talking to people not easy and that repeating the same things to everyone you meet is slightly cringe-inducing, but this is what you need to do.

The more people you pitch this series to (and I assume that you have an *elevator pitch* for this purpose) the more chance you have of finding the connectors: the people that can get you to the right people in the industry; so get out there start talking.

Oh, and see if you can get hold of a copy of the book I mentioned; there might be something more in the other chapters.

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't have much to say, but here's a couple things:

The first thing I have to say, why did you say "This show has a number of amazing characters and amazing character development for each character, including people of color, women and LGBT people." I mean, yeah, it's great that you do, but why do you have to sell it like that? LGBT people do need more representation, I agree, but you already said that you have a trans character (as the main, if I read correctly), so it's obvious that you have one or more LGBT characters.

And why would you mention the people of color one? I have nothing against POC, but why would you state that you've given their character deep character development. This should not need to be mentioned, since it should already happen. And the woman one. Are men not as important as men? Do men not need deep character development as well? I would like an answer to these two questions.

The second thing I have to say, I would suggest going about and finding a person who will take you in. (A good director, perhaps, or just a director) Do some research on what goes into a tv show. And research whatever else comes to mind.